# Cloud Functions for Firebase - Get current user id

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Spent a while searching out a solution to what seems a simple problem but... How can I get the current users details inside a cloud function (when not using an functions.auth trigger)?   I'm sure there must be a simple solution to this. (I hope)

Thanks for the replies... Just done that but how would I get the /user/uid from the Firebase DB within a storage triggered event? e.g.

```
exports.addUploadInfoToDatabase = functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {
  console.log("firebase storage has been changed");
  // need to find the uid in here somehow
  admin.database().ref(`/user/uid`).push({testKey:"testData"});
})
```

Applogies if I've missed the point in your replies.

Thanks...

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please show what you have already tried. Your question, as it currently is will probably not receive a good answer, and may be closed. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better results using this site.

Comment: It's not clear how the answer on the question flagged as the duplicate addresses the OP's question.

Comment: For those of you actually looking for an answer to this wrongfully flagged question, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56761633/6276471

Answer (score 40):

First you can get the current signed-in user tokenId by calling `getIdToken()` on the User: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getIdToken

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)
.then(function (token) {
    // You got the user token
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Then send it to your cloud function.

Then in your cloud function you can use: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Example:

```
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then(function(decodedToken) {
    var uid = decodedToken.uid;
    // ...
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error
  });
```

The documentation for decodedToken is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.DecodedIdToken#uid

DecodedIdToken contains the user uid, then you can get the user by calling this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getUser

Which returns a UserRecord https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord

Comment: Thanks for the reply...   "First you can send the current signed-in user tokenId from the client to your Cloud Function".... Do you mean pass a value to the cloud function?  I can't find any documentation to achieve that...

Comment: Added Javascript example to get the user token in client.

Comment: How do you access `firebase.auth().currentUser`? I got `firebase is not defined`. If you would already have a `currentUser`  why not directly get the `.uid?

Comment: @Francescu `firebase.auth().currentUser` is done on the client side (browser), when initializing your app you do: `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.0/firebase.js"></script>`  this script automatically creates the `window.firebase` object that you can call as `firebase` from anywhere.

Comment: I don't see how the proposed answer solves the problem. The poster is responding to a Firebase Event triggered by Google Cloud Storage, so there is no "client" where they can acquire the id token and pass it to the function. I am trying to solve a similar problem but with an event triggered by Firestore. I need access to the user that performed the Firestore op that caused the event to be triggered.

Comment: @MaxRoss-Google Indeed. What I do is make the `uid` part of the bucket path, and on the trigger side just parse the path from the event data to get the `uid` again.

Comment: Actually it is quite simple to do. Get the `uid` of the user that caused the change: `functions.database.ref('...').onWrite((change, context) => {  const uid = context.auth.uid; });` Then get the user using `admin.auth().getUser(uid)`.

Comment: @RandySugianto'Yuku' can you please explain that idea a little better?

Comment: const uid = context.auth.uid;