# Firebase Cloud Functions - How to get user that uploads a file?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have an admin web site that uploads files to a specific folder in Firebase Storage.

From a Storage cloud functions, I need to get the authenticated userId from the user that uploads the file. I need this because, when the user uploads the file, the cloud function starts, do some process, and save information in the realtime-database, where I need to save the responsible user of the upload action.

I saw that get user from a realtime-database cloud function is simple (using context.auth.uid), but I did not find any similar solution to storage cloud functions.

Is it possible?

Tks.

Comment: There is currently no metadata about the user associated with the Cloud Functions trigger from Cloud Storage. The workaround is to pass the information about the user in the path, using [Storage security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security) to ensure they are accurate.

Comment: Tks @Frank ! But my problem is that the authenticated user has no path in my storage and I'm trying to avoid create this path, upload file and then move it to the correct admin path just to get the userID.

Comment: If you want the UID in a secure way, you'll have to pass it in somehow, either in the path or in metadata.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the given answer is correct.  It demonstrates how to add the uid into the metadata, and use security rues to ensure that it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload custom metadata as an object containing String properties:

From documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata):

```
var metadata = {
  customMetadata: {
    'location': 'Yosemite, CA, USA',
    'activity': 'Hiking'
  }
}
```

Then you can use `getMetadata` on the file (the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata#get_file_metadata)) to retrieve its information or for example get `customMetadata` like in my trigger function below.

For example and from my iOS application, I created a `StorageMetadata` and I set the `customMetadata` to `["user":"userID_AZERRRRR"]`

In my node js functions, I developed the trigger function like this:

```
exports.testStorageOnFinalize = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(uploadedObject => {
    console.log('metadata keys', Object.keys(uploadedObject.metadata));
    console.log('metadata user', uploadedObject.metadata['user']);
})
```

In my log console:

> 3:00:20.140 PM info   testStorageOnFinalize **metadata user userID_AZERRRRR**

**Risks**

From Doug comment, this solution is not fully secure because the meta data could be faked.

So, **to resolve this**, we can use the security rules for storage in order to check if the user is equal to identified user:

```
// Allow reads if a certain metadata field matches a desired value
allow read: if resource.metadata.user == request.auth.uid;
```

You can check storage rules [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage/)

Comment: The problem here is that anyone could fake the metadata to pretend they are anther use, so this solution is not fully secure.

Comment: Thank you Doug, can we complete this solution with some security rules?

Comment: Possibly.  Why don't you consult the reference for storage security rules to see if there's any way to access the metadata for the file being uploaded?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage/

Comment: Yes indeed, so we can check for example `if metadata.user = request.auth.uid`

Comment: Sounds like a great addition to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would provide working code, as Ali Abbas' answer is not fully correct.

Add custom metadata to the file during upload. You *have* to use the customMetadata string>string object as shown below.

```
firebase.storage().ref("/location/path").put(file, {customMetadata: {'uid': firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}})
```

Next, we need to verify that all files uploaded contain this metadata and that it's accurate. Here's a working storage security rule:

```
allow write: if request.resource.metadata.uid == request.auth.uid
```

Finally, from the cloud function, the following will return the uid taken from the file's metadata:

```
object.metadata.uid
```

You can be sure that this is the uid of the person who uploaded the file, as they cannot be uploaded without it unless you're using the Admin SDK.